# Mysql 5.5 /phpmyadmin simple query mystery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

If I run this `select`-query on my PhpMyAdmin (version 4.0.5):

```
(SELECT *
FROM prenotazione
WHERE stato = 'prenotato'
AND (to_days( data ) +2) < to_days( NOW( ) )
)
```

that runs fine.

But if the I run a `delete`-query that doesn't work:

```
(DELETE *
FROM prenotazione
WHERE stato = 'prenotato'
AND (to_days( data ) +2) < to_days( NOW( ) )
)
```

Someone please explain, why this is happening.

Comment: Here is my concern too. Even if I use `delete` query in proper format but within a pair of **parenthesis** it shows some error but `select`-query runs fine.

Answer (score 4):

It's just

```
DELETE FROM ...
```

not

```
DELETE * FROM ...
      ^^^
```

For more information see [DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)

Comment: Though he was wrong there still doesn't run if it is inside a pair of **parenthesis**. Why is parenthesis not allowed here???

Answer (score 1):

Make the query like this:

```
(DELETE FROM prenotazione WHERE stato = 'prenotato' AND (to_days( data ) +2) < to_days( NOW( ) ) )
```

for more information check delete syntax [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Answer (score 0):

This work withouth * and parenthesis before and after the query

```
DELETE
FROM prenotazione
WHERE stato = 'prenotato'
AND (to_days( data ) +2) < to_days( NOW( ) )
```